# Angular: require property binding

Tags: typescript, angular9

Using Angular 9, I have a component defined as such

```
@Compontent({
  selector: 'app-whatever',
})
export class Whatever {
  @Input myProp: string
}
```

I have `tsconfig.json` to be strict, with `strictNullChecks` and `noImplicityAny`, for Angular I've declared `strictTemplates`. For good measure I even set `fullTemplateTypeCheck`.

While Angular does complain if I do this

```
<app-whatever [myProp]></app-whatever>
```

It does not complain if I don't bind any properties at all

```
<app-whatever></app-whatever>
```

Why is that? I want to catching missing prop bindings at static time, not during runtime.

If you have any suggestions, I appreciate it.

Comment: do u have ["fullTemplateTypeCheck": true](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options) in your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: @boop_the_snoot hello, yes I did

Comment: ok, then I don't have anything more to suggest, as I've not yet started with [angular9]

Comment: I don't think there currently is a way to achieve what you want, other than maybe throwing in a *wrong* type initially. Maybe you can create an issue over at the angular repository and request this behavior? Most definitely if the input does not define a possibly `undefined` type, then *not* passing any data (note: implicitly passes `undefined`) should be considered as wrong and thus report an error.

Comment: [**Check this**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18156#issuecomment-315774348)

Answer (score 0):

Bind the property in the selector `selector: 'app-whatever[myProp][myOther]'`